# Why doesn't this perl script crawl the links of those websites?

Tags: perl, web-crawler

I've been using Perl to crawl links in menus on several websites successfully but it seems that it doesn't work on the following webpages:

- http://www.uriminzokkiri.com/index.php?ptype=gisa1 (-> error 500)
- http://www.ournation-school.com/index.php?menu=treatise (-> blank text file)

Here are my two customized scripts:

This is the first website:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings ; 
use URI;
use Web::Scraper;
use Encode;
use Data::Dumper;

open (OUT, '>threadUrl_uriminzokkiri_gisa1.txt');

for (my $i=1; $i<=42; $i++)
{
    my $url="http://www.uriminzokkiri.com/index.php?ptype=gisa1&pagenum=$i";

    my $resultat = scraper 
    {   
        process '//div[class="gisatitle"]', 'entree[]' => scraper   
        {   
            process '//a/@href', threadUrl => 'TEXT';   
        }; 
    };

    my $res = $resultat->scrape( URI->new("$url") );

    for my $val (@{$res->{entree}}) 
    {
        print OUT Encode::encode("utf8", "http://www.uriminzokkiri.com/".$val->{threadUrl}."\n" );
    }
}

close (OUT);
```

This is the second website:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings ; 
use URI;
use Web::Scraper;
use Encode;
use Data::Dumper;

open (OUT, '>threadUrl_ournation-school_treatise.txt');

for (my $i=1; $i<=11; $i++)
{
    my $url="http://www.ournation-school.com/index.php?menu=treatise&cno=&pagenum=$i";

    my $resultat = scraper 
    {   
        process '//div[class="cu_title_con"]', 'entree[]' => scraper    
        {   
            process '//a/@href', threadUrl => 'TEXT';   
        }; 
    };

    my $res = $resultat->scrape( URI->new("$url") );

    for my $val (@{$res->{entree}}) 
    {
        print OUT Encode::encode("utf8", "".$val->{threadUrl}."\n" );
    }
}

close (OUT);
```

Does anyone know how, and could you give me some advice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is too broad. Please split this into two separate questions, one per script. Asking about two separate scripts in one question will result in confusion. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for your advice the Tin Man !